# Python: Connect Four Alternating turns

Tags: python

I've been working on a program that implements the game of connect 4 and I've hit a snag. Here's my output:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Player 1 please pick a column: 5
-----------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
-----------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   | x |   |
-----------------------------
Player 2 please pick a column: 6
-----------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
-----------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   | o |
-----------------------------
```

So basically the board isn't "updating" when alternating turns 
Essentially my code should end up looking like this:

```
-----------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
-----------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   | x | o |
-----------------------------
```

I'm not too sure what I have to do to get the board to update properly. I've tried messing around with the print functions but the output ends up getting worse than before. Here is my code:

from player import *

```
def play_game(board, player1,player2):
    b = ConnectFour()
    f = Human(1)
    g = Human(2)
    while True:
        f.play_turn(1)
        if b.is_game_over() == None:
            g.play_turn(2)
            if b.is_game_over() == None:
                pass
            else:
                print "Player 2 wins"
                break
        else:
            print "Player 1 wins"
            break
```

Basically: Player 1 plays, then we check if there's a winner if not player two plays, and so on. And this calls a separate class:

```
class Human(Player):
    def play_turn(self,board):
        super(Human, self).play_turn(board)
        b = ConnectFour()   
        x = raw_input("Player %s please pick a column: " % self.playernum)
        b.play_turn(self.playernum, int(x))
        b.print_board()
```

Any ideas, input or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems your code is incomplete. Is it pasted from an earlier version?
In particular, the passing of the board object isn't clear. `play_game` and `play_turn` expect a board parameter but it isn't passed, and then they use `b = ConnectFour()` which isn't shown.
Please elaborate.

Comment: It looks like you create a new `ConnectFour` ever turn. Shouldn't you only create one throughout the game?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, although you're passing `board` objects around, you ignore them and just create new ones everywhere.

First, look at `Human.play_turn`:

```
def play_turn(self,board):
    super(Human, self).play_turn(board)
    b = ConnectFour()   
    x = raw_input("Player %s please pick a column: " % self.playernum)
    b.play_turn(self.playernum, int(x))
    b.print_board()
```

This passes `board` to the super method `Player.play_turn`, but then it creates a new board `b = ConnectFour()`, and everything it does is to *that* board, not the original one.

Likewise, in `play_game`, you take a `board`, and a `player1` and a `player2`, but do nothing with them, and instead create new ones called `b`, `f`, and `g`.

So, what you want is something like this:

```
def play_game(board, player1,player2):
    while True:
        player1.play_turn(board)
        if board.is_game_over() == None:
            player2.play_turn(board)
            if board.is_game_over() == None:
                pass
            else:
                print "Player 2 wins"
                break
        else:
            print "Player 1 wins"
            break

class Human(Player):
    def play_turn(self,board):
        super(Human, self).play_turn(board)
        x = raw_input("Player %s please pick a column: " % self.playernum)
        board.play_turn(self.playernum, int(x))
        board.print_board()
```

That should fix your immediate problems—but I'm guessing you have very similar problems in all of your other functions.

Meanwhile, there are some odd things about your design.

For example, why are you checking `if b.is_game_over() == None:`? A function called `is_game_over` should probably be returning something truthy if the game is over, and something falsey if it's not. While `None` is a reasonable "something falsey", `False` is even more reasonable—and, either way, it's hard to imagine why you'd want to check for it explicitly, instead of just checking that it's falsey. (Plus, even if you *do* need to check specifically for `None` for some reason, there's almost never a good reason to use `== None` instead of `is None`.)

Second, why do you need to create `board`, `player1`, and `player2` outside of the `play_game` function? It doesn't seem like they'd be all that useful outside this function.

Finally, even with just two players, I think your code would be simpler if you refactored the common parts:

```
def play_game(board, player1,player2):
    while True:
        for player in player1, player2:
            player.play_turn(board)
            if board.is_game_over():
                print "Player {} wins".format(player.playernum)
                break
```

One last thing: Your logic doesn't seem to account for the possibility that the game might be over because the current player has no move to make. I'm not sure if that's a tie or a loss in Connect 4, but I'm pretty sure it's not a win, is it?

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help! I applied what you told me and my program works great! As for your concerns about the None thing--this program is an assignment for one of my CS classes and long story short that was just how the project was set up. But I really appreciate the advice and I will most certainly try to apply more of your tips :)